# How is overflow integer stored in java? Why?

Tags: java, integer-overflow

I saw in another question that we can use this formula:

`((x + 2^31) mod 2^32) - 2^31`

The result should be what x is actually stored. But I still don't understand how we get this formula.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int x = 5;
    System.out.println((x + Math.pow(2, 31)) % Math.pow(2, 32) - Math.pow(2, 31));
} //Prints 5
```

Comment: Instead of just mentioning "another question", it would be helpful if you include a link to that question.

Answer (score 0):

That formula works because of the following principle: `int`s in Java fall within the range `[-2^31, 2^31)`. First, observe that `2^32 = 2*2^31 = 2^31 + 2^31`. Since the formula takes `2^31` and adds a value that can *maximally* be `2^31 - 1`, the maximal value of `(x + Math.pow(2, 31))` is `2^32 - 1`, and the minimal value is `0` (`-2^31 + 2^31`). When doing division modulo `2^32`, any such value must be itself. That is, `y % z == y` when `0 <= y < z`. Now, since `y` is `(x + Math.pow(2, 31))` and `z` is `Math.pow(2, 32)`, the output from `(x + Math.pow(2, 31)) % Math.pow(2, 32)` is equal to `x + Math.pow(2, 31)`. Since that is the case, the final output is `(x + Math.pow(2, 31)) % Math.pow(2, 32) - Math.pow(2, 31) == x + Math.pow(2, 31) - Math.pow(2, 31) == x`. Therefore, the result is always `x`, the input.

For integer values that overflow the limit in either direction, the best way to think of this is intuitively: the `- 2^31` at the end is what sets the lower-end limit of `-2^31` for an `int`, and the `mod 2^32` defines the number of values that the `int` can take, `2^32`. Since `n` values starting from `-2^31` fit in range `[-2^31, -2^31+n)`, the overall range for an `int` is `[-2^31, 2^31)`, as I asserted previously. The `+ 2^31` in the inside of the formula cancels out the modification to the value caused by the `- 2^31` on the out/right side of the formula, and the modulo operation keeps the values from going outside the range.